# Two parameters for URL Rewrite in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a simple five page website which includes a blog.  This is the first time I'm using .htaccess to correctly rewrite my URLs for SEO friendly optimization.

The two parameters I am trying to allow a visitor to use is **sitename.com/blog/category/WORD** or **sitename.com/blog/SLUG**.  If /category/word is used, I'd want it to list all the posts with the chosen category word.  If /slug is used (short title of a post such as "learn-how-to-code"), I'd want it to just show that specific post.

Here's my old .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It was originally working fine for single pages, such as **sitename.com/about**, **sitename.com/contact** and so on, but any time I tried sitename.com/blog/SLUG or sitename.com/blog/category/WORD it would just redirect to the blog page.  I am echoing $_GET['category'] and $_GET['slug'] in blog.php to test it, but it never showed anything.

After looking at a few posts here, I figured out that I needed to add some separate lines to just check on /blog being used and to pull in the appropriate parameters.

Here's my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([^\.]+)$ blog.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^\.]+)$ blog.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The **sitename.com/blog/SLUG** is working fine, but anytime I do **sitename.com/blog/category/WORD**, it's showing "category/WORD" as the slug, and not breaking it into the category word.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: just switch the lines like `RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^\.]+)$ blog.php?category=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^blog/([^\.]+)$ blog.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple explanation without tech is for better clarification

`Line1   RewriteRule ^blog/([^\.]+)$ blog.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
 Line2   RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^\.]+)$ blog.php?category=$1 [NC,L]`

in line 1 you are doing regular expression checking by code `([^\.]+)` after the url `blog`
and in line 2 your `url` is kind of hard coded part of `category` and then you are doing `regular expression` check

so in simple work regular engine never goes to the line2 of code because it already become part of line1  is already checked and passed `regular expression` part so `category` becomes part

**simple tip: Always keep hard url parts first and `regular expression parts` rules at the end.**

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to swap your ^blog lines.  Since the first one is using the L flag, you're essentially telling it to stop using other rules, so it's already picking up $1 as category/WORD in your case.

I don't know how the rest of your backend is setup, but you could also look into routing everything through an index page.